# null Object in Iterator

Tags: java

```
List<String> wideTableData = new ArrayList<>();
wideTableData.add(null);
wideTableData.add(null);
Iterator<String> iterator = wideTableData.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String firstValue = String.valueOf(iterator.next());
    System.out.println(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(firstValue));
    System.out.println(firstValue.equals("null"));
}
```

The code above doesn't make an exception near String.valueof. In fact, firstValue equals String "null".
Why?

Comment: That is how `String.valueOf` works. It returns the string "null" for null values. Did you read its documentation?

Comment: Why should it produce an exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj)
{
  return obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

String.valueOf implemented like that.
As you see in codes, if the input object is null,  then the result "null" string.